# How to test if a method isn't called after N seconds?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, xctest, ohttpstubs

I'm writing some tests and I need to check that "nothing happens" when the app receive a request, that request has to be completely ignored. The way to know if the request was ignored or not is to check two delegates that have to receive nothing after the request is sent.

I have no idea how to test this:

```
func testIgnore() {

    sut.message() {
        //this doesn't have to be called if test succeed
    }

    sut.appointment() {
        //this doesn't have to be called if test succeed
    }

    stub(isHost("test.com")) { (request: NSURLRequest) -> OHHTTPStubsResponse in
        let data = "specific data".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return OHHTTPStubsResponse(data: data!, statusCode: 200, headers: nil)
    }

}
```

Any idea?? I'm completely lost, because I can't use expectations because if the expectation timeouts that's a failed test and this scenario that would be a successful test...

I need to wait for example 3 seconds, if the blocks are not called then that's a success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `XCTFail()` in the two methods you expect not to be called so your test will fail if they do get called.

Then simply use XCTest methods for asynchronous testing to wait for 3 seconds, e.g.:

```
let exp = self.expectationWithDescription("3 seconds passed")
dispatch_after(…3 seconds…, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  exp.fulfill()
}
self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(4)
```

⚠️ This is pseudo-code as I'm on my iPhone so it's hard to write long code there, and I may have done some typos in the methods names. Adjust as needed.

---

*PS: I don't see how this question is related to `OHHTTPStubs`, btw. All your question is about is "how to test if a method isn't called after N seconds"…*

Comment: just changed the title, you are right... it makes more sense that way.